# Angular JS simple API: only showing data that begins with the word 'request'

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, api, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have been tasked with creating a simple AngularJS API. I have the basics down to display the data but it will only grab data from the JSON file that beings with request. so in the be low data, the table displayed visually will not show 
{{ x.colour_name }}, it basically completely ignores it.

HTML

```
   <table style="text-align:center">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
    <th>Request ID<td>{{ x.request_id }}</td></th>
    <th>Request Time<td>{{ x.request_time }}</td></th>
    <th>Request Completed<td>{{ x.request_completed }}</td></th>
    <th>Request Customer<td>{{ x.request_customer }}</td></th>
    <th>Colour name <td>{{ x.colour_name }} </td></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Here is my script

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('requestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.slick-tools.com/testproject/api/v1.0/feed/data").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data.data;
  });
});
</script>
```

Stumped!

Comment: Can you post the array of JSON data inside of myData?

Comment: Here is the link to it. http://www.slick-tools.com/testproject/api/v1.0/feed/data

Comment: What is wrong with it? why will it not display anything but arrays that begin with request?

Comment: you aren't looking in the proper array for that property either

Comment: *"What is wrong with it ?"* ... already said that you can't nest `<td>` in a `<th>` only in `<tr>`

Comment: Thank you, I have now fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

The `colour_name` is in the `thread` objects inside the `data.threads` array. Access it like `x.threads[0].colour_name`.

Comment: @user3594401 note that this only gives you the first one...some have more than one

Comment: @charlietfl Good point, it looks like Sandeep has a good answer to address that.

Comment: Yep the other answer fixes that, I never noticed about the mutiple colours so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="text-align:center">
<tr>
 <th>Request ID</th>
 <th>Request Time</th>
 <th>Request Completed</th>
 <th>Request Customer</th>
 <th>Colour name </th> 
</tr> 
<tr ng-repeat="x in myData">
<td>{{ x.request_id }}</td>
<td>{{ x.request_time }}</td>
<td>{{ x.request_completed }}</td>
<td>{{ x.request_customer }}</td>
 <td><p ng-repeat="thread in x.threads">{{ thread.colour_name }}</p> </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Try this .. It might help

Comment: what about the rest of the `threads`? This simply ignores them

Comment: We can run a loop for displaying the color name for each thread in the threads array

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<table style="text-align:center">
  <tr ng-repeat="x in myData track by $index">
    <th>Request ID<td>{{ x.request_id }}</td></th>
    <th>Request Time<td>{{ x.request_time }}</td></th>
    <th>Request Completed<td>{{ x.request_completed }}</td></th>
    <th>Request Customer<td>{{ x.request_customer }}</td></th>
    <th>Colour name <td><span ng-repeat="c in x.threads track by $index">{{ c.colour_name }}, </span> </td></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('requestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://www.slick-tools.com/testproject/api/v1.0/feed/data").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WaOmEGWcqeEj5Afg6w7Y?p=preview), handling multiple colors here:

```
    <td><p ng-repeat="thread in x.threads">{{ thread.colour_name }}</p></td>
```

Table looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: Cool! Happy to help!